# Run MPI program from console on several Windows machines

Tags: windows, port, mpi, mpich

I'm trying to execute parallel MPI program on several Windows machines (actually I have one Win7 and one WinXP machines, but people with other configurations (WinXP on all machines, for example) have the same problem). I use MPICH2 (1.4.1p1). I can execute program if I use wmpiexec (MPIEXEC wrapper - GUI for MPI) but if I try to execute it from console I catch next error:

Command: `mpiexec -hosts 2 locahost 2 192.168.0.102 2 <path to the program>`
Error: `mpiexec running on <name of my machine> is unable to connect to msmpi service on locahost:8677`

I have created rule for the program in Windows firewall.
So where can be a problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a wierd solution, but when `mpiexec.exe` and `executable MPI-program` is in the same directory everything is fine.