# mpiexec unable to connect to msmpi service in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mpi

when ever I tried  this command

```
mpiexec -hosts 2 192.168.22.23 1 192.168.22.24 1 c:\sarah\mpiparallel.exe
```

I get these errors:

```
 _ mpiexec running on SARA-PC is unable to connect to msmpi service on 192.168.22.2
    3:8677

    Other MPI error, error stack:
    MPIDU_Sock_post_connect_filter(1278): unable to connect to 192.168.22.23 on port
     8677, exhausted all endpoints
    MPIDU_Sock_post_connect_filter(1328): unable to connect to 192.168.22.23 on port
     8677, No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused i
    t.  (errno 10061)_
```

I really search alot about these errors but I couldn't find any useful thing!

Comment: You already found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787647/run-mpi-program-from-console-on-several-windows-machines)?

Comment: I tried it,and copy the executable file in the mpiexec folder, but the error still exists

Comment: And you checked firewall/anti virus settings? You can `ping 192.168.22.23`?

Comment: yes,I can ping it(this address is my own ip address) and i have turned off the firewall, but what should I do about the antivirus?

Comment: what does `netstat -an -p tcp` tell you? Does it list a listening port 8677 (if that service is on the same box)

Comment: no,I don't have this port in the listening list, so what should i do?how can I add this port by command line?

Comment: I added it via advance setting firewall, but again I can not see it in result of nestat -an -p tcp!!!

Comment: well, it looks like the smpd process is not running according to [this](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/055a904c-cc88-4273-a8d3-970781b09f0d/how-to-run-program-on-multiple-machines-by-mpiexec?forum=windowshpcmpi). Unfortenately I have no further knowledge of those tools. Just one last check: Did you run it elevated (run as administrator)

Comment: You can also take a look at the answer I posted on your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313508/how-to-use-job-submit-in-windows-command/21314400#21314400). It won't necessarily fix this issue, but it could solve your overall problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'va alsogot these error codes when trying to run MPI apps on an HPC cluster. Nodes are Windows 8 in my case. The issue was caused by the Firewall.

You may allow individual exe files to go through the Firewall on each individual node, which is time consuming, or you can disable the Firewall which is unsafe.
I did the second since I have an internal network for computational purposes and no safety issues therefore.

You can try to disable the Firewall to make sure your problem is solved that wayand then decide what to do.

Hope this helps.